# Does this sentence violate Subject-Verb agreement rules?

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement, singular-they

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> It is irksome when some colleague inflicts *their* tasks on you by telling you about *his* more urgent tasks.

The person in question is a male, but still this construction seems a bit awkward. Is it acceptable at all?

Comment: Better to use either _his_ or _their_ for both.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thanks! Still, is the sentence acceptable?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "inflicts his/their tasks on you". Do you mean that he makes you do his tasks as well as your own?

Comment: No I mean the person tries to make me do that person's tasks (for whatever reason.)

Comment: That's what I said!

Comment: Yes, sorry. That's what I mean @Kate Bunting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sentence uses the **singular *they***, which is often used when mentioning a person whose gender is unknown, irrelevant, or both. This is correct usage.

Many years ago, style guides recommended using the **generic *he*** when referring to a person of unknown gender. Even today, some people will tell you that the singular *they* is incorrect. It is not incorrect.

However, it is incorrect to use *they* in the first part of the sentence and *he* later on. Whether you use *they* or *he*, you should be internally consistent.

Comment: Thank you, @randomhead!

Comment: Many legal documents still include a clause which says that use of masculine pronouns shall include the feminine.